# Payment Gateway Integration in Android

Tags: android

I am building  an android application what is the best payment gateway available with sdk in order to make payments and which can accept all major  debit and credit cards across the globe ?I have gone through many threads but could not able to find out the major differences between google wallet and paypal in terms of integration.

Comment: Google wallet (In app purchase) will charge 30% of transaction amount and paypal will charge just 2.5 or 3%, this is the major difference.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, because questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1):

best way for it i found was use PAYU in web view, most app like snap deal, flipkart are using that gateway. just load payU in web view and other work will done by third party. [check this](https://www.payu.in/signupCampaign?utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_content=lcm&utm_term=payu&utm_campaign=search_main&gclid=COnpuIGzt8YCFRcQjgodzuYAQw)